# php sessions in multi part form

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm trying to build a two page sign up form, and I'm having some troubles. First page has two inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="email" size="37">
<input type="password" id="password" size="37">
```

and second page more fields. Following a tutorial, I'm having trouble getting the values from the first page on my next one via post method. I'm using this following code:

```
<?php

 session_start();

 session_register('email');
 session_register('password');

 $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
 $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];

?>
```

but the session_register is displaying a blank page. If i comment the two session_register the page loads normally.

Can anyone help out please? Thank you.

Comment: `session_register` is way outdated, and has been removed with PHP 5.4.0. You need to go and find a more up-to-date tutorial. (And update your debugging skills – the most basics common steps of debugging PHP would have told you already that that function does not exist.)

Comment: Regarding session_register: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php (so, you don't need it). Also, you need 'name' attribute in both form fields, and lastly: echo vars to see what you got...

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Forgot the name attribute. And thanks for the heads up for updating me on the outdated thing